# HTML5 time input max and min without JavaScript

Tags: html, validation

I was asked to constrain the time input to times between 8.00 am and 12.00 am (midnight), but no matter how I try I cannot get it to work. Does anyone have a solution for how to set the input's max time as 12am and min time as 8am? Can I do this without using JavaScript?

```
 <div class="rTableRow">
<div class="rTableCell"><label for="time">Time :</label>
 </div>
 <div class="rTableHead">&nbsp; 
 <input type="time" min="08:00:00" max="24:00:00" />
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: There is an HTML `<time></time>` tag. You can learn more here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp

Comment: @vadim_hr  i tried that its the same as mine ...but still it cannot work ..it ignore the max and min..

Comment: it is not supported by every browser, so you have no chance do this without javascript

Comment: Here is the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). iOS Safari does not support `min` and `max`. FireFox doesn't support `type="time"`. Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Android are the only ones that support it currently.